# Problems with refactoring java code

Tags: java, loops, refactoring

I am doing my homework right now and have a question about refactoring my code in Java.
I am working on a Sudoku right now and I need to check if the 3x3 boxes are valid or not. To do that I create a one dimensional array with all the numbers of the boxes and later I compare the value of them. It is working right now but it really isn't refactored at all. I would really like to know if there is any way to reduce all this copy paste.

```
public static boolean validFieldParts() {
    int counter = 0;
    boolean isValid = false;

    int[] copyArray1 = new int[field.length];
    int[] copyArray2 = new int[field.length];
    int[] copyArray3 = new int[field.length];
    int[] copyArray4 = new int[field.length];
    int[] copyArray5 = new int[field.length];
    int[] copyArray6 = new int[field.length];
    int[] copyArray7 = new int[field.length];
    int[] copyArray8 = new int[field.length];
    int[] copyArray9 = new int[field.length];


    // copy the array

    // 1 große Feld
    for (int i = 0; i < field.length / 3; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < field[i].length / 3; j++) {
            copyArray1[i * 3 + j] = field[i][j];
        }
    }

    // 2 große Feld
    for (int i = 0; i < field.length / 3; i++) {
        for (int j = 3; j < 6; j++) {
            copyArray2[i * 3 + j - 3] = field[i][j];
        }
    }

    // 3 große Feld
    for (int i = 0; i < field.length / 3; i++) {
        for (int j = 6; j < 9; j++) {
            copyArray3[i * 3 + j - 6] = field[i][j];
        }
    }

    // 4 große Feld
    for (int i = 3; i < 6; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < field[i].length / 3; j++) {
            copyArray4[(i - 3) * 3 + j] = field[i][j];
        }
    }

    // 5 große Feld
    for (int i = 3; i < 6; i++) {
        for (int j = 3; j < 6; j++) {
            copyArray5[(i - 3) * 3 + j - 3] = field[i][j];
        }
    }
    // 6 große Feld
    for (int i = 3; i < 6; i++) {
        for (int j = 6; j < 9; j++) {
            copyArray6[(i - 3) * 3 + j - 6] = field[i][j];
        }
    }

    // 7 große Feld
    for (int i = 6; i < 9; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < field[i].length / 3; j++) {
            copyArray7[(i - 6) * 3 + j] = field[i][j];
        }
    }

    // 8 große Feld
    for (int i = 6; i < 9; i++) {
        for (int j = 3; j < 6; j++) {
            copyArray8[(i - 6) * 3 + j - 3] = field[i][j];
        }
    }

    // 9 große Feld
    for (int i = 6; i < 9; i++) {
        for (int j = 6; j < 9; j++) {
            copyArray9[(i - 6) * 3 + j - 6] = field[i][j];
        }
    }

    Arrays.sort(copyArray1);
    Arrays.sort(copyArray2);
    Arrays.sort(copyArray3);
    Arrays.sort(copyArray4);
    Arrays.sort(copyArray5);
    Arrays.sort(copyArray6);
    Arrays.sort(copyArray7);
    Arrays.sort(copyArray8);
    Arrays.sort(copyArray9);

    for (int i = 1; i < copyArray1.length; i++) {
        if (copyArray1[i] == copyArray1[i - 1])
            counter++;
        else
            continue;
    }
    for (int i = 1; i < copyArray2.length; i++) {
        if (copyArray2[i] == copyArray2[i - 1])
            counter++;
        else
            continue;
    }
    for (int i = 1; i < copyArray3.length; i++) {
        if (copyArray3[i] == copyArray3[i - 1])
            counter++;
        else
            continue;
    }
    for (int i = 1; i < copyArray4.length; i++) {
        if (copyArray4[i] == copyArray4[i - 1])
            counter++;
        else
            continue;
    }
    for (int i = 1; i < copyArray5.length; i++) {
        if (copyArray5[i] == copyArray5[i - 1])
            counter++;
        else
            continue;
    }
    for (int i = 1; i < copyArray6.length; i++) {
        if (copyArray6[i] == copyArray6[i - 1])
            counter++;
        else
            continue;
    }
    for (int i = 1; i < copyArray7.length; i++) {
        if (copyArray7[i] == copyArray7[i - 1])
            counter++;
        else
            continue;
    }
    for (int i = 1; i < copyArray8.length; i++) {
        if (copyArray8[i] == copyArray8[i - 1])
            counter++;
        else
            continue;
    }
    for (int i = 1; i < copyArray9.length; i++) {
        if (copyArray9[i] == copyArray9[i - 1])
            counter++;
        else
            continue;
    }

    if (counter > 0)
        isValid = false;
    else
        isValid = true;

    return isValid;

}
```

Comment: You should use loops to change the range of `i` and `j`.

Comment: how exactly can i do that?

Comment: @NumanTakács check my updated answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using 9 different arrays and 9 different loops to represent each section of 9, I would have another nested for loop that iterates over each cluster using the same array.

```
//Iterate over each 'block'
for (int row = 0; row < 3; row++) {
    for (int col = 0; col < 3; col++) {
        //Iterate over each cell in the block
        for (int i = row*3; i < (row+1)*3; i++) {
            for (int j = col*3; j < (col+1)*3; j++) {
                copyArray[(i - 3) * 3 + j - 3] = field[i][j];
            }
        }

        //Sort array and do duplication check here - return false if dupe found
    }
}
return true
```

This would cut down on the length of your code, although it may not be more efficient.

Instead of using a counter flag, it would be much faster to instead return false whenever you would have incremented the counter, and to return true at the end. This would prevent unnecessary code from running

Answer (score 0):

Here a complete refactoring. Here the improuvements:

- Created two new methods: `createCopy` and `isValid`
- Deleted unused variables `counter` and `isValid`
- Substituted 9 arrays with one two size array.

The code as not been tested, please take a bit careful attention on method createCopy in particular.

```
// Creates each block of 9 digits copying digits from field 
// row, col are the block position, starting from upper left 0, 0 to
// last block 2, 2 
public static int[] createCopy(int[] field, int row, int col) {
    int[] copy = new int[9];
    for (int i = 3 * row; i < 3 * row + 3; i++) {
        for (int j = 3 * col; j < 3 * col + 3; j++) {               
            copy[(i - 3 * row) * 3 + j - 3 * col] = field[i][j];              
        }
    } 
    return copy;
}

// Check if one block is valid
private static boolean isValid(int[] copyArray) {
    Arrays.sort(copyArray);
    for (int i = 1; i < copyArray.length; i++) {
        if (copyArray[i] == copyArray[i - 1]) {
            // Exit immediately if not valid
            return false;
        }
    }   
    return true;
}

// Create blocks, then validate them
// At first not valid block return false
public static boolean validFieldParts() {
    int[][] copyArrays = new int[3][3];

    for (int row = 0; row < 3; row++) {
        for (int col = 0; col < 3; col++) {
            copyArrays[row][col] = createCopy(field, row, col);
        }
    }


    for (int[] copyArray : copyArrays) {
        if (!isValid(copyArray)) {
           // Exit immediately if not valid
           return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```